# Pass id from php to JS file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I know very well that this question is ask many time but some how my problem is different and i didn't find the solution.

Now comes on issue.

I have a an image,so whenever i click on to the image the pop up window is open and show the data.now i want to make this dynamic and wants that the data should be come according to the id.

here is my image code.:

```
<div id='contact-form'>

        <a href='#' class='contact'><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/pre.jpg" style="height:18px; width:18px"></a>
      </div>
        <!-- preload the images -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <img src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/img/contact/loading.gif' alt='' />
        </div>  


And on its click the ajax is called from js file here is the code of that js file:
//here the provider is controller and show_coupon_pre is a function which call the view having the data.
$.get("provider/show_coupon_pre", function(data){
                    // create a modal dialog with the data
                    $(data).modal({
                        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                        position: ["15%",],
                        overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
                        containerId: 'contact-container',
                        onOpen: contact.open,
                        onShow: contact.show,
                        onClose: contact.close
                    });
                });
```

I have a table having no of records and each record having this type of image.where the user can click and get the preview in pop  window.
But i want to show the data in pop up according to the row like for id=1 it should be show the data of id==1 and so on. now can you you guys please help me how can i pass this id to the js file by which i can fetch the required data.

I am working in codeignitor.

Comment: Here's the answer to your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653651/including-php-variables-in-an-external-js-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td><img class="banner" src="/image1.png" post_id="1"></td>
 <td>some other data 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 <td><img class="banner" src="/image1.png" post_id="2"></td>
 <td>some other data 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.banner').click(function() { 
  post_id = $(this).attr("post_id");

  // send your ajax with post_id
} );
```

Comment: That is not valid html.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags

Comment: I just give you idea, how to solve this problem. It is impossible to solve write code for solving your problem, because i don't know how html page generated and all code works.

Comment: @Maxim but how can i pass this variable to ajax calling url $.get("provider/show_coupon_pre", function(data){

Comment: I think it will look something like this:

$.get('provider/show_coupon_pre?coupon_id'+post_id);

Comment: I will explain logic step by step:
1. Generate html table with image attribute (see example of this html that i put on this respone)
2. Add onclick for such image (i think you already made this)
3. On "onclick" event, get from caller your attribute value
4. Initialize ajax:  $.get('provider/show_coupon_pre?coupon_id'+post_id, function(data) { YOUR CODE HERE. Open Modal To user });

Comment: @maxim when i alert this post_id than it gives undefined.

Comment: This is invalid HTML. So: this is not the correct answer to the problem. Using this will make your website invalid and unstable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID in php when outputting the image, I would do this:

```
<script>
var randomId = <?php echo '"' . $phpId . '"'; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: now how can i pass this java script variable to my js file where the ajax is calling.

Comment: Place my example above the include of your JS file. You should be able to access it. e.g alert(randomId) It should be in scope.