# How to use variables from a php file in a js file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I have the following file structure:

[image]

Now I want to use the variables from the dropdown menu's (that are in the get_attributes.php, get_fields.php and in the get_tables.php) in my main.js and in getData.php . Now the question is how can use a variable from another .php file in a .js file?

Comment: here is the answer of your question
[Access PHP var from external javascript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928827/access-php-var-from-external-javascript-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use PHP variables from JS scripts.

### Dynamic access

If you want get variables dynamically you can use AJAX ([see jQuery AJAX doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ).

### Static access

If you want to access PHP variables when your JS app start you can put PHP variables in the DOM by using this syntax :

```
<input type="hidden" id="php_name" value="<?=$name?>" />
```

And use jQuery to get it :

```
$('#php_name').val();
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: You don't need hidden input you can use `<script>var name = <?=json_encode($name)?>;</script>`

Comment: I like to have possibility to put all JS in a JS file. So I prefer add data to DOM.