# How to get PHP var on javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

How to get PHP Var from external js file? 
However, this variable is the dynamic used in the table.
itry this [Access PHP var from external javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928827/access-php-var-from-external-javascript-file) but the data shows the same results

this my js code

```html
$('[id^="device"]').change(function() {
     opt = $(this).val();
     if (opt=="mikrotik") {
         $('[id^="info"]').html('<center><small>Copy Perintah, dan masukan di Terminal Mikrotik : <br> (Silahkan sesuaikan server, password, dan username  vpn)</small></center>');
         $('[id^="command"]').html('<center><pre> /interface ovpn-client add connect-to='+server+' password=''+password+' user='+username+'</pre></center>');
     } else if (opt == "linux") {
        $('[id^="info"]').html('<center><small>Copy Perintah, dan masukan di Terminal Linux : </small></center>');
        $('[id^="command"]').html('<center><pre>bash <(curl -sSL https://git.io/fjiNM)</pre></center>');
     } else if (opt == "windows-old") {
        $('[id^="info"]').html('<center> Silahkan ikuti tutorial berikut ini <a href="https://docs.hostddns.us/docs/vpn-remote/tutorial-remote-mikhmon-dengan-vpn-remote/"> https://docs.hostddns.us/docs/vpn-remote/tutorial-remote-mikhmon-dengan-vpn-remote/</a></center>');
        $('[id^="command"]').html('');
     } else {
       $('[id^="info"]').html('<center> Silahkan ikuti tutorial berikut ini <a href="https://docs.hostddns.us/docs/vpn-remote/tutorial-remote-mikhmon-dengan-vpn-remote/"> https://docs.hostddns.us/docs/vpn-remote/tutorial-remote-mikhmon-dengan-vpn-remote/</a></center>');
       $('[id^="command"]').html('');
     }
 });
```

Note : i will show this on modal inside table list

Comment: So you trying to make Ajax request right?

Comment: What inputs are you using to make thous changes?

Comment: Yes, true, i use ajax request

Comment: I guess you have a javascript type error, try : `$('[id~="device"]').change(function()`

Comment: the program doesn't work

Comment: `$( "input[name^='news']" )` thats what says in documentation. Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many way to access PHP variable from external/internal java-script.

1. By declaring global js variable to header. Example -

```
    <?php $example_php_var = 'Example';?>
    <html>
     <head>
       <title>Example</title>
       <script>
           (function(){  window.example = '<?php echo $example_php_var;?>';  })(); 
       </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
   </html>
```

2. By Ajax. Example ---

   **ajax.php**

```
<?php
 $example_php_var = 'Example';
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode(['example_php_var' => $example_php_var]);
?>
```

**example.js**

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
     $('example').click(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url: 'ajax.php',
         method: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(response) {
               let example = response.example_php_var;
         }
       });
     });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

3. Use php file as javascript
   **example.php** 
   (give output as javascript. You can use this php file link as js link)

```
<?php $example_php_var = 'Example';?>
(function(){
     var example = '<?php echo $example_php_var;?>';
     alert(example);
})();
<?php
header('Content-type:text/javascript');
?>
```

> You can use above mentioned php file as javascript link -

```
<script src="example.php"></script>
```