# Passing PHP variable to an external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to test this out with my code, and it's grabbing it as undefined.

I'm posting this because my reputation isn't at 50. I'm trying to test what this person was saying: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24310507/11852136 .

As summarized, it clearly echos it out, but when I try grabbing the value, it comes back as undefined.

file bin/A.php:

```php
<?php
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$SomethingElse = '';
$TestGrab = 'MEHOY MENOY!';

echo "Hi ".$fname."!";
echo nl2br ("\n");
?>
<input type="hidden" id="Error" value="<?php echo $TestGrab ?>" />
```

file B.js:

```
$.ajax({ type:'POST',
   url: 'location/bin/A.php',
   data:{fname:fname},
   success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var grabbing = $("#Error").val();
      console.log("Error: " + grabbing);
   }
});
```

What I expected it to do was for `console.log("Error: " + grabbing);` to output to the console `Error: MEHOY MENOY!`, but instead it gives me `Error: undefined`. Can I have some instructional help?

Comment: what is `<input type="Error" ...` ?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I fixed that.

Comment: you need to put response from ajax to some `<div></div>` then get value of `#Error`

Comment: Please check with `var grabbing = $(data).find("#Error").val();` or `var grabbing = $(data).val();`

Comment: You also need a `;` in your `echo` part else PHP will error. So change `<?php echo $TestGrab ?>`   to   `<?php echo $TestGrab; ?>`

Comment: @GBWDev No, it's not necessary if the php tags contain only one command (generally, the last command in between php tags does not need the terminator), which is the case here.

Comment: @El_Vanja you are right, but as far as you know its the last one.. but it might not be

Comment: @GBWDev I'm going by the posted example. It's clearly the only command between the tags. It's not a bad practice to add it, I just wanted to point out that it will not error.

Comment: @ThatDummyOverThere Have you linked to the proper answer in that other question? Because you're saying you want to test what that person said, but the linked answer didn't use ajax.

Comment: Use your browser debugger to see exactly what PHP is sending.  You'll get the exact string back in `data` but that will not have anything to do with subsequent attempts to find `$("#Error")` because the contents of `data` are not part of the DOM.  Traditionally, you send the response back JSON-encoded.